# Why answerer should pay price of somebody wrongly down-voting the answer

Tags: discussion, reputation

What happens when somebody down-votes the answer and later realizes that he was wrong but the answerer has lost his 2 points even after answering correctly.

If down-voter later votes up the answer as part of penitence or something, then it ok because answerer will actually earn extra 8 point.

But if down-voter doesn't vote up or is unwilling then why the answerer should lose points and pay for somebody else's mistake?

I see there is no mechanism to handle this situation. It has just happened to me.

**Edit:**  The down-voter has accepted in discussion through comments that his understanding was wrong. Now, he don't anything for vote up or undo vote down, what should answerer do?

Comment: People can undo votes you know... downvotes OR upvotes...

Comment: The very last part of your question seems to assume that it is not possible that your answer is bad/wrong or that someone might consider it to be so.

Comment: Please study a little about the rep system in SE, then if you did have problems, ask on meta.SE. As it currently stands, this shows neither of those from you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does "Reputation" work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work)

Comment: The down-voter has accepted in discussion through comments that his understanding was wrong. Now, he don't anything for vote up or undo vote down, what should answerer do?

Comment: @nicael no, it's totally not a dupe.

Comment: @Sha Fifth point.

Comment: @nicael this here is discussion about "why" and feature request asking to change it. It can't possibly be dupe of something explaining the dry "what" and I'll reopen it with my hammer if it gets closed.

Comment: @nicael you can close ALL questions discussing reputation as dupe based on your logic and actually burninate the [tag:reputation] tag.

Comment: @Sha Why not? *goes closing everything...*

Comment: @nicael use a script and exploit a bug.... cya in one year? ;)

Comment: @Sha *goes cloning her account, just in case...*

Comment: See the situation here, people are unobjectively misunderstanding the situation and question, and blindly down voting, when I have clearly tagged "feature-request" and talked about mechanism to handle such situation....

Comment: @hagrawal Actually my downvote is 100% clear and not blind - I totally disagree with what you suggest.

Comment: But @ShadowWizard I appreciate how you try to prevent this getting closed but...I only see confusion in this post and no clear proposal. And it is tagged FR **and** discussion. I vote to close to clearify the discussion. If this turns out to be a feature request, in its current state I vote as unclear. Just put the cream in the fridge, I feel ice cream coming...

Comment: Even implementing something for that is really hard; additionally, what would its use be? *Retracting* downvotes? Am I the only one who sees your suggestion vague and not clearly defined?

Comment: @rene OP suggesting *something* that will revert the -2 in case the downvoter admitted via comments he/she made a mistake, even if they fail to actually undo the downvote. Not that I agree, but it's clear enough.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Not a problem, I respectfully accept it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, you win this time. I see your point, vaguely, but granted, you are correct.

Comment: All, I am least bothered about this virtual world of reputation but I am bothered about whether a piece of software has mechanism to handle a given situation or not? That's the reason I have tagged "discussion" and "feature-request" which i guess many failed to see or understand, or may be I misunderstood the these tags ... So, the whole point here is whether there is a mechanism or not, if not then contrasting it advantage and dis-advantage to make a system more complete...

Comment: @hagrawal How is software supposed to judge whether a vote is valid or not? Voting is strictly the opinion of the voter, and as of 2015, software cannot read people's minds.

Comment: @Mysticial But it can have a feature to counter that? I hope someday will come when your interesting thought of software reading people's mind come true!!! Amen!!!

Comment: If comments were needed to convince a down voter there is/was nothing wrong with the post. That is enough reason for downvotes, including all its side effects.

Comment: @hagrawal best I can think of is adding auto message when a downvoter post comment after downvoting "Keep in mind you can undo your vote for five minutes after voting, or after the post is edited" - I'll still be against this suggestion, but it's more feasible than what you currently suggest here.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thank you for your inputs. All, I am done, thank you for your time to have a look on this question. Have a nice day.

Comment: @nicael There is a bug in your duplicate suggestion :D

Answer (score 9):

> If down-voter later votes up the answer as part of penitence or something

It doesn't work like that. If a downvoter recants, they undo the downvote (+2). If they then upvote, that's a different thing (and +10).

> But if down-voter doesn't vote up or is unwilling then why the answerer should lose points and pay for somebody else's mistake?

And if they don't think they made a mistake? There is a large amount of presumption in your question.

Comment: The down-voter has accepted in discussion through comments that his understanding was wrong. Now, he don't anything for vote up or undo vote down, what should answerer do?

Comment: Nothing. Accept that this happens. Life is too short to worry about imaginary internet points, in particular when one upvote == 4 * downvotes

Comment: I am least bothered about the this virtual world of reputation but the point I am trying to bring is what feature SO has to handle this situation? And if not then do we need it?

Comment: What _situation_? The rare occurrence of someone admitting a bad downvote and not reversing it? It doesn't happen often enough to put anything in place for it - the most one can do is ask the downvoter to reverse the downvote. At that point, leave it. We don't tell people how to vote and don't force voting on them (vote fraud is a different matter).

Comment: Exactly, I am not one among who will ask people to please please vote up again!!! But I am the one who believe in making the system as flawless and feature-full as possible.

Answer (score 3):

> If down-voter later votes up the answer as part of penitence or something, then it ok because answerer will actually earn extra 8 point.

Ummm... If the downvoter reverses their downvote into an upvote, the answerer will regain the lost points from the downvote and get 10 more points for an upvote, bringing in 12 rep. If they only undo the upvote, the answerer will gain back the 2 points from the downvote. Simple.

> But if down-voter doesn't vote up or is unwilling then why the answerer should lose points and pay for somebody else's mistake?

This is really what we cannot control as a community. As an answer upvote equals to 5 downvotes, the community can help with upvotes as they give the answerer significantly more points than he loses unless they gain too many downvotes. We really don't know whether they were wrong or not so it is up to the universal honor system. Be honest and undo the downvote (if you can) or lie and don't. I say be honest!

Oh, sometimes what you think is right might be wrong to another. Votes are used to see whether they were helpful or not, to themselves not other people. After x minutes you lose the privilege to reverse your previous vote so that may be the reason (you can vote again if someone successfully edits the post *after* you voted on it.

> The down-voter has accepted in discussion through comments that his understanding was wrong. Now, he don't anything for vote up or undo vote down, what should answerer do?

Just try to go on with life. Not everyone is perfect nor everyone can reverse their vote as explained in above paragraph. 2 points can be easily recovered with an edit unless you earned the privilege to instantly edit a post. A good post can earn you some quick points, especially if you answer. Questions can also be a good rep earner too.

Sometimes, all it takes is an edit to the post. The community might find it more useful and upvote it more and more. Maybe it can even convince the downvoter to reverse their downvote into an upvote or at least remove it. Getting the answer accepted is even better! That's 15 points, which can only be cancelled out by 8 downvotes (-16 rep). Anyways, just move on and try to earn the rep back. 2 points isn't that much (if you are a new user, this doesn't apply to you. 2 points can be a lot for new users).